# How to select data from hdf5 file that matches condition

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, keras, h5py

I have a hdf5 file that contains data used to train and test a neural network created using Keras train_test_split and writing to a hdf5 file(structure shown below)

[image: Data Structure]

I want to test the network on a subset of the data that matches some specific conditions. I have a list of the index values of this data that match this condition, I would like to select all of the entires in ix_test with these values that and get an array of the corresponding X_test variables but am not sure how to do so.

```
f = h5py.File(filename,"r")
```

I first would want to match all the index values from my list to the corresponding entries in ix_test, I know as a slow method I could loop over both and do something like,

```
matching_vals = []
ix_test_set = f['ix_test'][:]

for i in idx_List:
    for j in ix_test_set:
        if j == i:
            matching_vals.append(j)
        else:
             pass
```

But I imagine there must be a smarter numpy way to check all the values in ix_test and return the values that match an entry in my idx_list. Once I have that what is the quickest way to then select the X_test values with those index values.

Comment: Are you open to using PyTables to access your hdf5 data instead of h5py? If so, PyTables has several ways to read Table data from a dataset into a NumPy array. Methods are `.read_where(condition)` and `.read_coordinates(coord_list)`.

Comment: Another idea: You can use a NumPy masked array to mask the values you don't want. (A masked array is an array of True/False values that matches your data aray.) You can create the mask from `idx_List`. Use True for values you want from `ix_test_set`. Many NumPy methods have an equivalent for masked arrays (use `ma.method()` instead of `np.method()`).

Comment: Thanks yes that works well, I used `np.in1d` to get the masked array and then used `np.where` to get the required indices for X_test and y_test